# How does Enqueue function works after certain number of dequeues

Tags: java, queue

I am using the following link http://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/queue-data-structure to understand implementation of queue functions but i don't understand for example--> if i have a queue of size 5 and the input values are 1 ,2,3,4,5 where 1 is at front and 5 is at rear and queue is implemented using array ,in that case if i dequeue 1,2 and 3 such that front is now at index 2 and rear is at 4(Array length is 5,so last index) .Now if i try doing enqueue to insert new values will i not have to shift all the values towards front so that i can insert at the rear and if i do so many shifts how does enqueue happens in O(1) time  .Please help me understand this

Comment: Think of the array as "circular".  You would put the new value at index `0`.

Comment: Hi james ..thanks ..so u mean the indexes which were earlier occupied by 1,2 and 3 would be pointed by rear now and insertions will happen at index 0,1 and 2 now right? also i wanted to know if we always assume a circular array when implementing queue?

Comment: Well, the code in the link you provided would actually tell you the queue is full, but a better implementation would be to treat it as circular, and then yes, next entries would be at index 0 1 2.  As far as implementation, you can't assume anything.  There are tons of ways of implementing anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot james ..got it u mean FiFo(linear) queue will end with the last entry at rear while circular queue will start filling from 0th index :)

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a queue as **a bank line**, the first one comes is the first to out(**FIFO**).
when you dequeue an element from the queue then all elements shifted automatically and so on.
and you can add more elements at the rear as long as you don't exceed the allowed size.
and for further info http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html

Comment: [5][4][3][2][1] This is the Queue of fixed size 5 ,rear points at 5 and front points at 1,now we perform Dequeue trice so that [5][4][][][] is the queue and Rear still points to 5 while front now points to 4 i want to know assuming that it is a FiFo Queue ,now i want to enqueue values 7 and 8 ,but Rear being already at the end of   our fixed size queue how do we insert without shifting values 5 and 4 ..and if we shift them towards front ..then how is it O(1) operation and as said by james does that imply always a circular queue so that we insert at index 0..please confirm

Comment: when you perform dequeue(), you will have this form [][][][5][4]... not as you imagine , in the queue the enqueue operation only takes place at the rear(end).. read the tutorial carefully

Comment: I got this wonderful link where you can pause and start animation for all data structures..it would be help to other   http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Algorithms.html ...and thanks :)